Partial Index Exclusion Clause Performance
Whats the time complexity for checking exclusion clauses during indexed queries, for example
CREATE INDEX title_idx_german ON films WHERE title NOT IN ('a','b','c','d','e');

INSERT INTO title_idx_german(title) VALUES('f'); 
-- planning...
-- checking constraints...
-- checks for exclusion <-- how long does this take?


Why do you think it's not linear?  Just one test to decide whether to update the index or not.

Just check the query plan using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)

The check for NOT IN ('a','b','c','d','e') will be vastly faster than inserting a new entry into the index.
